# Не работает curl на локальном сервере

Tags: curl

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать в следующем случае:

1. В разрабатываемом проекте на локальном сервере (Linux) не парсится сайт (используется curl)
2. В этом же проекте на хостинге парсинг проходит без каких-либо ошибок (все в порядке)
3. Сайт, который парсится, открывается только через vpn

Comment: На каком языке вы используете CURL, Если на С++ то я тоже заметили когда отключён интернет не работает с локальным сервером, то если включён то без проблем работает локально, как бутто в инициализацыи он проверяет есть ли интернет.